# How do i make my own created shell work with .sh files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

My teacher gave us this assignment to create our own shell. Our shell is supposed be called rshell and is supposed to work like the regular shell.

I created my own shell using C++. If you type a command like `ls` in my created shell it gives you a list just like how if you typed `ls` in the regular shell.

The problem I am facing is how do I get the `.sh` files or script files to work with my created shell. I noticed when I run a `.sh` file using my shell it does not run the `.sh` file through my shell. It runs it through the regular shell. How do I make `.sh` files run through my shell?

Answer (score 5):

Change the hash-bang line of the scripts to point at your shell. For instance,

```
#!/usr/local/bin/rshell
```

Or wherever your shell executable is.

Answer (score 4):

As John already said, change the shebang to point to your shell. The kernel will invoke the command in the shebang with the file itself as an argument. To demonstrate, try a file with a shebang of `#!/bin/cat`.

```
#!/bin/cat
hello world
```

It pretty much behaves the same as if you typed `/bin/cat /path/to/file`.

The shebang does not have PATH lookup capabilities, so `#!yourshell` would not work as a shebang. However, you can use `env` to do the PATH lookup as in `#!/usr/bin/env yourshell`. (This approach is preferred for commands that are at different paths on different systems, like python.)